# How do I Align my widgets with MediaQuery for all devices in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I have three widgets that I am trying to align on my screen in refernce to each other.

I have a golden border that I want to set as my background, the wheel in the center and the center of the wheel which is also a seperate asset.

I have aligned the assets using MediaQuery however every time I debug it on a different device the MediaQuery has some difference and the alignmnet isn't proper.
This is how Im calling my widgets:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
//this is for the GOLDEN BORDER
              Positioned(
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.082,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/app/border3.png',
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  )),

//This is the WHEEL
              Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.344),
            Container(
              //color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withAlpha(180),
              child: Center(
                child: Winwheel(
                  handleCallback: ((handler) {
                    ctrl = handler;
                  }),
                  textFontFamily: 'Netflix',
                  controller: ctrl,
                  numSegments: 3,
                  outerRadius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.41 / 2,
                  innerRadius: 28,
                  strokeStyle: Colors.white,
                  textFontSize: 20.0,
                  textFillStyle: Colors.white,
                  textFontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  textAlignment: WinwheelTextAlignment.center,
                  textOrientation: WinwheelTextOrientation.horizontal,
                  wheelImage: 'assets/app/spin2.png',
                  drawMode: WinwheelDrawMode.code,
                  drawText: true,
                  imageOverlay: false,
                  textMargin: 0,
                  pointerAngle: 0,
                  pointerGuide: PointerGuide(
                    display: true,
                  ),
                  segments: <Segment>[
                    Segment(
                        textFontFamily: 'Netflix',
                        fillStyle: Color(0xff9b57fc),
                        textFillStyle: Colors.white,
                        text: '400',
                        strokeStyle: Colors.transparent),
                    Segment(
                      textFontFamily: 'Netflix',
                      fillStyle: Color(0xff17a8f9),
                      textFillStyle: Colors.white,
                      text: '400',
                      strokeStyle: Colors.transparent,
                    ),
                    Segment(
                      textFontFamily: 'Netflix',
                      fillStyle: Colors.pink,
                      textFillStyle: Colors.white,
                      text: '900',
                      strokeStyle: Colors.transparent,
                    ),
                    Segment(
                      textFontFamily: 'Netflix',
                      fillStyle: Color(0xffef225b),
                      textFillStyle: Colors.white,
                      text: '500',
                      strokeStyle: Colors.transparent,
                    ),
                  ],
                  pins: Pin(
                    visible: false,
                    number: 16,
                    margin: 6,
                    // outerRadius: 5,
                    fillStyle: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                  animation: WinwheelAnimation(
                    type: WinwheelAnimationType.spinToStop,
                    spins: 4,
                    duration: const Duration(
                      seconds: 15,
                    ),
                    callbackFinished: (int segment) {
                      setState(() {
                        isPlaying = false;
                      });
    
                      print('animation finished');
                      print(segment);
                    },
                    callbackBefore: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isPlaying = true;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),

//This is the GOLDEN CENTER

              Positioned(
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.285,
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.359,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/app/center.png',
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.16)),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
```

I am using the [winwheel](https://pub.dev/packages/winwheel) dependency for the Spinning wheel.
This is what the final output looks like. It isn't properly aligned in all devices even though it looks fine in the image

[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try usign AspectRatio Widget with an aspectRatio of 1.0 to keep the width and height the same (as a circle) and align the stack in the center

```
Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 1.0, //Give it an aspectRatio of 1
          child: MyWidget()
        ),
      )
  ),
),

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center, //align the Widgets to the Center of the Stack
      children: [
        //this is for the WHEEL
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.orange[800],
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
        ),
        //This is the GOLDEN BORDER
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 20, color: Colors.yellow),
            color: Colors.transparent,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
        ),
        //This is the GOLDEN CENTER
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 12,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.yellow[200],
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
        ),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

I don't have the assets so I make some Containers with colors but it should look like that

[image]

So for you try it without the positioned widgets (the Stack is now centered so there is no need)

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center, //align the Widgets to the Center of the Stack
      children: [
        //This is the WHEEL
        Winwheel(
         ....
        ),
        //this is for the GOLDEN BORDER
        Image.asset('assets/app/border3.png', fit: BoxFit.contain), //or try BoxFit.scaledown if that doesn't work
        //This is the GOLDEN CENTER
        Image.asset('assets/app/center.png', width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 12, fit: BoxFit.scaleDown)
      ]
    );
  }
}
```